# NotificationCenter not working in didSelectRowAt in iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, notifications

Hello 
I wanna send notification to another view controller like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("thisIsTestNotif"), object: nil)
}
```

Thus set this in viewDidLoad:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(thisistestHandler),name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue:"thisIsTestNotif"),object: nil)
```

and in the following:

```
func thisistestHandler(notification:Notification)  {
}
```

but it does not work. The main problem is accrue when set call method in didSelectRow method.

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: where you add notification center observer?, i think your class is not initialized where you add observer.

Comment: @Hitesh First init and then call it in another vc.

Comment: `thisistestHandler` initialization is wrong, preferred @vadian answer

Comment: @reza_khalafi ! You should try with the delay! For example: Post your notification after 0.01 seconds or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector for your observer is wrong. Your notification observer method takes parameter, you have not specified that while adding observer for that method in the selector parameter. The fact that your project is compiling means there must be another method with the same name but with no parameters.

Change to:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ............
    ............

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(thisistestHandler(notification:)),name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue:"thisIsTestNotif"),object: nil)
}

@objc func thisistestHandler(notification:Notification)  {

}
```

Comment: But when set call method in viewDidLoad it works correctly.

Comment: @reza_khalafi: When you are sendng notification from another view, does the viewcontroller which is registered as an observer is in memory?

Comment: Yes thank you. i have removed observer somewhere in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable – and ObjC compatible – Swift 3 syntax is

```
#selector(thisistestHandler(_:))
```

and

```
func thisistestHandler(_ notification: Notification)  {...
```

Of course the receiver of the notification must have been loaded already.

---

Note:

If the controllers are related then protocol / delegate or closure callback are the better choice. A `Notification` is supposed to be used only if there can be multiple receivers or sender and receiver are not related.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `viewDidLoad`

Add

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(thisistestHandler),name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue:"thisIsTestNotif"),object: nil)
```

in `viewWillAppear` and remove observer in `viewWillDisappear`.

Just try not sure but might be work for you.